# Linking a QR Code straight to video

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, qr-code

I am trying to link a QR code to open a video.

At the moment I have used a QR generator to point to the video file URL. But when using it on my phone it asks me to click the link first.

Is the the functionality of the QR code reader, or is there a way to program the QR image to bypass this and directly open the video player?

Also, with the current functionality, it works on Android, but opening in iPhone (using the QR code) doesn't play any sound. If on the iPhone I go straight to the URL, then the sound does play.

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Where's the question? I'd guess this should be all you have to do. If there's another prompt or the video opened immediately depends on the client or user's system and is outside your scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a function of the reader. I've used QR readers that both tell me the metadata then ask if I want to open and ones that unilaterally open without asking me. Personally I like being told what the QR code is before I visit it as it gives me a heads-up on what it's trying to do before it does it.