# How to use a QR code to link a video?

Tags: video, qr-code

Hello and thank you for your time:
I'd like more information about how to use QR codes to embed a video. It is related to making a pamphlet where I need to include a way to show a video which is a company's announce, but I have not used those codes before.
I need some references to start with!

I have read similar topic as: 
[Linking a QR Code straight to video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817802/linking-a-qr-code-straight-to-video)
and
[How to use a computer's webcam to read a qr code and open a website [Java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283178/how-to-use-a-computers-webcam-to-read-a-qr-code-and-open-a-website-java)

But I need a generator or service already implemented!

Comment: Find a QR code generator and input the url to your video?

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps below:

1. Upload/Pick your Video for your QR Code.
2. Create the QR Code Linking To Your Video.
   There are some QR code generators, for example: GoQR.me
   Once you are there, select the URL tab and insert your link.
3. Test Your QR Code Link To Your Video.
   Pickup your mobile phone and open up your QR code reader. Scan your QR code video link that you just created.
4. Get the QR Code Out